# An amazing approximation of $e$

Tags: approximation, constants

As we can read in Wolfram Mathworld's article on approximations of $e$, the base of natural logarithm,

> An amazing pandigital approximation to e that is correct to $18457734525360901453873570$ decimal digits is given by $$\LARGE \left(1+9^{-4^{6 \cdot 7}}\right)^{3^{2^{85}}}$$ found by R. Sabey in 2004 (Friedman 2004).

The cited paragraph raises two natural questions.

1. How was it found? I guess that Sabey hasn't used the trial and error method.
2. Using which calculator can I verify its correctness "to $184\ldots570$ decimal digits"?

Comment: "Using which calculator..." that is not math within the scope defined by the help center, but the first question is answerable.

Comment: More on 1. can be found [here](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/mathmagic/0804.html).

Comment: It is not that astonishing, once we realize it is a small variation on $$e=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n $$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The astonishing bit is the pan-digitality, I think.

Comment: The Friedman reference is http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/mathmagic/0804.html See also https://www.quora.com/How-did-Richard-Sabey-come-up-with-the-below-equation-which-is-accurate-to-over-a-septillion-digits and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721650/checking-approximation-of-e

Comment: Well, $$ e-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \frac{e}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right), $$ hence if $n$ is a colossal number, the approximation is extremely good. Still no wonder.

Comment: An even better approximation comes from $$ e-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1/2}=-\frac{e}{12 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right).$$

Comment: The second question is answerable too, and I believe that it can be within the community's scope. The main point would be to communicate that any decimal representation of an expression is the result of an algorithm. Typical calculators just cut off the execution of this algorithm to a few digits, but in principle we can go on. And there are plenty examples where we have done just that... continue the execution of the algorithm (think of the billions of digits of $\pi$ we know of). Next step would be to give examples of algorithms that would calculate any digit of the expression given above.

Comment: One more reference: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449877/pandigital-rational-approximations-to-the-golden-ratio-and-the-base-of-the-natur

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you very much for finding all the references. You can post the comments as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: The point is that you don't have to compute the number to know how many digits are accurate. You "just" compute the error term and take its base $10$ log.

Comment: WolframAlpha [reproduces](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=IntegerPart%5B-Log%5B10,+E%2F2%5D%2BLog%5B10,9%5D*(4%5E42)%5D) the cited error using the (first) approximation cited by Jack above: $$\frac{e}{2\cdot 9^{4^{42}}}=10^{\log_{10} e/2\cdot 9^{4^{42}}}=\frac{1}{10^{-\log_{10}(e/2)+4^{42}  \log_{10} 9}}\approx \frac{1}{10^{18457734525360901453873569}}$$

Comment: @Jack, can you come up with a pandigital instance of the better approximation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}
(1+9^{-4^{42}})^{3^{2^{85}}}
&=(1+9^{-4^{42}})^{3^{2*2^{84}}}\\
&=(1+9^{-4^{42}})^{9^{2^{84}}} \\
&=(1+9^{-4^{42}})^{9^{4^{42}}}\\
&=\Bigl(1+\frac1{9^{4^{42}}}\Bigr)^{9^{4^{42}}}\qquad\text{where }=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n.
\end{aligned}$$
This is just the limit definition of $e$ with a large number as an approximation for $\infty$.

**Edit:**
[Numberphile](https://youtu.be/xgBGibfLD-U) just did a video on this, which also gives a pandigital approximation for $\pi$, but it's only accurate up to ten digits.

Comment: Wow! So it is just a joke..?

Comment: @Eric It’s like a party trick.

Comment: @Eric No, it's not easy at all to make it pandigital, all digits from $1$ to $9$ are used exactly once.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Fair enough. Its freaky accuracy isn't a mystery, though.

Comment: That's right, all you need is a large $n$ for that.

Answer (score 2):

This may be best answered by looking for an improvement to that formula, and explaining how to find it.

The basic idea for all those approximations for $e$ is to write some large number $N$ in two different ways, using exactly the digits from $2$ to $9$, and then take $(1+\frac{1}{N})^{N}$ as an approximation for $e$. In Sabey's old (2004) example, he writes $N_{old}=3^{2^{85}}=9^{4^{6*7}}$. However, using a small digit like $3$ as the base of the exponential tower isn't optimal. For example, if we could find a way to replace the $3$ by a $5$, that would make $N$ much larger, and the resulting approximation much better...
Finding such an $N$ that works actually isn't too hard: Using $N_{new}=5^{3^{84}}$ frees up the digit $2$, which conveniently can be used to write $\frac{1}{5}$ as either $.2$ or $0.2$, depending on how you like to write your decimal numbers. At the same time, we have lost access to the digit $4$, which we have to take care of: Using properties of the exponential function, we can write $N_{new}=5^{9^{42}}=5^{9^{6*7}}$. The digit $4$ is no longer needed, so $(1+.2^{9^{6*7}})^{5^{3^{84}}}$ or $(1+0.2^{9^{6*7}})^{5^{3^{84}}}$ is a valid pan-digital solution, which is equal to $e$ up to $8368428989068425943817590916445001887164$ decimal places.
I'd be surprised if even this new solution was optimal. I replaced the digit $3$ by a $5$ in the base of the exponential tower, but using any of the digits $6$ through $9$ could lead to an even better solution. Maybe give it a try yourself!

About your second question:

The formula $e=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}{(1+\frac{1}{N})^{N}}$ actually approaches $e$ in a very predictable way. If you have an approximation $(1+\frac{1}{10^{n}})^{10^{n}}$, it will differ from $e$ by exactly $1.359...\times10^{-n}$, regardless of the value of $n$ (which can be any sufficiently large number). As a consequence, the number of correct decimal digits will always be equal to either $n$ or $n-1$. In general, $(1+\frac{1}{N})^{N}$ will be correct up to $\log_{10}{N}$ digits (or sometimes one less).
The number $3^{2^{85}}$ has $18457734525360901453873570$ digits, and Sabey's approximation is correct to that number of decimal places. The new solution $5^{3^{84}}$ has $8368428989068425943817590916445001887165$ digits, and my approximation turns out to be correct to $8368428989068425943817590916445001887164$ decimal places.
Unfortunately, I am not aware of an online calculator that will tell you whether a particular approximation is correct to $n$ or $n-1$ digits, respectively, but maybe you're okay with knowing the answer to within $\pm 1$? You can check the size of $N_{new}$ using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=5%5E3%5E84).

Erich Friedman actually asks on his [Math Magic](https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/0804.html) to get in touch if improvements to his puzzle solutions are found, which I just did. I guess he'll update his page accordingly.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I owe you an explanation for the 1.359... part. That's e/2; see https://oeis.org/A019739 (the "formula" section).