# Using four integers from $1$ to $20$ to approximate $\pi$

Tags: number-theory, approximation, pi

> How close can you get to $\pi$ (as close as possible) using these rules?
>
> 1) You can only use at most four integers ranging from $1$ to $20$, each only once.
>
> 2) You can only use *plus*, *minus*, *multiply*, *divide*, *exponential*, and *log* as *binary operators*.
>
> 3) You can only use *integer factorial* as a *unitary operator*.
>
> 4) You should work in the real number region.

The best answer that I know currently is 
$$3 + \frac{16}{5!-7} = \frac{355}{113}  = 3.141592920\ldots$$

Comment: An answer given 6 years ago in a similar Q... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445277/pi-estimation-using-integers

Comment: That is good but the crucial point here is that you could only use four numbers and only once.

Comment: I agree about that, and will ask: where you found (source or reference) the detail regarding the current record?

Comment: Well the word “record” may not be appropriate, the above formula was given by one of my friends which relate to the famous “fractional approximation” of $\pi$.

Comment: $355/113$ is a known convergent of $\pi$ (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiContinuedFraction.html) and as well the funny article (https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/roots-of-unity/don-8217-t-recite-digits-to-celebrate-pi-recite-its-continued-fraction-instead/). See also (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_coincidence). Besides, IMHO, one can loose a lot of time on those things without real mathematical interest.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, I will not try to find the answer myself. Just curious about whether there is some well-known result or trick on this kind of composition.

Comment: I am not experienced to program the tree of the possible expressions but someone should be able to determine the best approximation by brute force.